# No me compila mi aplicacion flutter en androidStudio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Tengo un gran problema con este error no me compila la aplicacion, me pueden ayudar, ya intente todo actualizar el gradle , el flutter , flutter clean , flutter run --verbose, y no funciona

*Ofresco un pequeño reconocimiento por paypal :(*

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_simple_video_player-0.0.9/lib/flutter_simple_video_player.dart:124:33: Error: No named parameter with the name 'isInitialRoute'.
        settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: false),
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart:499:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const RouteSettings({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 900

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Córrela desde terminal con la opción --stacktrace a ver qué te dice?

Comment: me resulta muy difícil dar una soluciones  si ver el código, por favor publique como tiene el código para dar una solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la ùltima actualizaciòn de Flutter [se removiò el parametro `isInitialRoute`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51435) , puedes revisarlo en este commit:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51435

la dependencia que usas no ha sido actualizada  ya que esta usando el parametro `isInitialRoute` :

```
Navigator.of(context)
          .push(PageRouteBuilder(
        settings: RouteSettings(isInitialRoute: false),
        pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            ) {
          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: animation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
                body: PlayView(controller),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ))
```

lo puedes ver en el còdigo:

https://github.com/ruihuancao/flutter_page_video/blob/master/lib/flutter_simple_video_player.dart

---

Te sugiero usar otras opciones como "YoYo Video Player" :

https://pub.dev/packages/yoyo_player

o tambièn "Chewie":

https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar y te cuento como me va, porque ahora no estoy en casa , donde tengo el proyecto pero muchas gracias por el dato , te aviso si me funciona

Answer (score -1):

Sin ver el codigo y atendiendo al mensaje del error diria que le estas pasando un parametro no valido al constructor del objeto RouteSettings:
[RouteSettings](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings/RouteSettings.html)